# Why is Julia giving me StringIndex error?

Tags: string, julia

I'm getting a `StringIndex` error for one particular string out of 10,000 which I am processing. I don't really know what the issue is with this string. I think it is probably a special character issue.

If I `println` the string then assign it to `txt` then pass `txt` to the function, I don't get an error. I am a little baffled.

I am sorry, I can't post the string as it is protected content and even if I did copying and pasting the string somehow removes the source of error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand. The details of how `String` is represented in Julia are explained in [the Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#Unicode-and-UTF-8-1).

You can use `eachindex` to get an iterator of valid indices into a `String`. The reason why it is an iterator is that you cannot efficiently (i.e. in O(1) time) find an index of i-th character in the string. However, you can use `isascii` function on a `String` to check if it consists only of ASCII characters (in which case byte and character indices are the same).

Also if you need to get to some specific character in a string you usually need probably more than one character, in which case `first`, `last` and `chop` functions are useful (actually `last(first(s, n))` gives you a character at position `n`; although it is not most efficient - iterating `eachindex` will allocate less).

Answer (score 4):

In Julia Strings are indexed by bytes rather than characters. You should use `for c in str` rather than trying to index manually.